# CSS menu pseudo element after not working in chrome

Tags: css

I have created a pure CSS menu and it works great in all browsers except Chrome and Safari. The menu should display arrow on the right but it moves to bottom.

When I change `white-space: nowrap;` to `white-space: normal;` it works fine on all browsers except Chrome and Safari and when I set it to `white-space: nowrap;` it shows arrow to the bottom

Code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jason99/ygtes/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `:after` to `:before`. It will still be floated right, but a new block context is not created by the `<li>` itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/ygtes/1/

Comment: Works perfect, but arrow is slightly moved on right side in Chrome. Removing float:right fix arrow position but it moves arrow to the left

Comment: @jason get rid of the `width: 8px`

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Not sure whether I should ask second question here.. Do you know the unicode of this arrow http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/2006/unicode.png

Comment: @jason no, but you could probably just use a `v` of a certain font