# :after pseudo not working in all modern browsers except Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm creating an HTML5 form and I have the following css working in all modern browsers except Chrome:

```
input:focus:required:invalid:after, textarea:focus:required:invalid:after { content: "!"; font-size: 20px; margin: -18px 0 4px 0; text-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); display: block; float: right; color: #c40000; }

input:focus:required:valid:after, textarea:focus:required:valid:after { content: "\2713\0020"; font-size: 20px; margin: -18px -4px 4px 0; text-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); display: block; float: right; color: #009c00; }
```

This should display an exclamation(!) when the input text is invalid and a checkmark(✓) as it does in all other browsers but for some reason Chrome just doesn't like it.

I've tried using the :before pseudo instead as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488348/css-menu-pseudo-element-after-not-working-in-chrome) but it doesn't work either. The css shows up in Chrome's Developer Tools Styles but there's nothing showing up. Please no suggestions saying "Why don't you use a small image instead of the actual characters" as this is unacceptable. All other suggestions are greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2):

That's because you aren't supposed to use pseudo-elements on [replaced content](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width) as its content isn't defined by CSS, but rather the OS in most cases (for form elements). I would imagine the implementations would vary amongst browsers because of this.

From the [Generated and Replaced Content Module:](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#replacedContent)

> Replaced elements do not have '::before' and '::after' pseudo-elements; the 'content' property in the case of replaced content replaces the entire contents of the element's box.

Comment: Sure, you can *style* replaced elements but as my quote alludes to you are not supposed to use the before & after pseudo-elements on them. Chrome is just following guidelines ..

Comment: That is true of anything lower than HTML5 & CSS3. Starting with HTML4 the certain form elements have been allowed to be styled with CSS and since HTML5 & CSS3 developers have been given near total access to style the input via CSS and it works completely fine on modern browsers. I've seen plenty of cases where people style form elements via pure CSS: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/27/css-form-elements-problem/                   http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/10/26/custom-style-all-your-form-elements-with-pure-css-and-no-javascript/

Comment: Ahhh now I see what you're saying... CSS will work on replaced content but not :pseudo elements.

Answer (score 1):

Guess I'll have to use some jquery to get it to work in Chrome and across all other browsers:
http://api.jquery.com/after/

or stray away from the :after pseudo class completely and just make the input boxes that are required red or something.